# trying to pass pointer to int to a function that takes pointer to long, how to do this

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, pointers

here is the function

```
template <typename T> T sum(T *x, T *y)
{
    T z(0);
    z=*x+*y;
    return z;
}
```

I am learning templates at the moment.

Here is what I am trying to do in main subroutine:

```
int i(1), j(2);
long p(12), q(3);

std::cout<<sum(&i,&j)<<" is the output\n";
std::cout<<sum(&((long)i),&q)<<" is the second output\n";
```

The bit sum(&((long)i),&q) is not working. Is there anyway that I can call the function using variable i without having to put its value in another variable of type long and than call the function sum using this other variable? I can understand that the way I have written the template, it will generate functions where both parameters are of the same type. I guess making it generate functions of parameters having 2 different types will not be that hard at all, I guess that this is another alternative.

Comment: Why does your `sum` function take pointers? Why not just `const T&`?

Comment: I did not think of that, I just thought well lets use pointers and make the very first example hard. It is 2315 here, may I shouldn't have done this.

Comment: OK, so I'm confused as to why you want to pass a pointer (or reference) to an integer to a function - it just makes everything more complicated for absolutely no reason. Is this because in reality, your types are something else, that DOES make sense to pass as pointers/references? [That is, this is a sort of XY question, in a way]

Comment: I changed it to use lvalue references instead. Even now I cannot make it take (long)i   as a parameter, even though I am casting it.

Comment: @quantum231 2315? C++ is still actively being used 302 years in the future? **damn!!!** Is quantum computing widely available (hence your nickname)? Also are the Kardashians still reality stars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using pointers in your `sum` function. There is no point in using them here. You could use const references, since the parameters won't be modified inside the function body:

```
template <typename T> 
T sum(const T &x, const T &y)
{
    T z(0);
    z=x + y;
    return z;
}
```

When you call the function using 2 argument of different types, the compiler won't be able to deduce the template argument type. Therefore, you need to explicitly indicate which one you want:

```
std::cout << sum<long>(i, q) << std::endl;
```

You could also cast one of the parameters, in that case the compiler will be able to deduce the type:

```
std::cout << sum(static_cast<long>(i), q) << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 You can also leave the explicit cast in place, like this: [link](http://ideone.com/ge5una).